# Python Plotly How to remove datetime gaps in candle stick chart?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, python-datetime, yahoo-finance, candlestick-chart

I am trying to remove the datetime gaps in my candlestick (the gaps are the time periods when the stock market is closed, hence there are not data). Can't seem to find a good solution for using plotly graph object. Is there a feasible way to do so?

[image]

My code is as follows (using plotly graph object):

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
import dash_html_components as html
import numpy as np
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.express as px
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

df= yf.Ticker('aapl')
df = df.history(interval="5m",period="5d")
df["Datetime"] = df.index

trace1 = {
    'x': df.Datetime,
    'open': df.Open,
    'close': df.Close,
    'high': df.High,
    'low': df.Low,
    'type': 'candlestick',
    'name': 'apple,
    'showlegend': False
    }

data = [trace1]

# Config graph layout
layout = go.Layout({
        'title': {
            'text': str(input_value) + ' Stock',
            'font': {
                'size': 15
            }
        },
        'plot_bgcolor': '#2E2E2E'
    })
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by rangebreaks in plotly.

Below is the code to hide outside trading hours and weekends.

```py
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['date'], open=df['Open'], high=df['High'], low=df['Low'], close=df['Close'])])
    fig.update_xaxes(
        rangeslider_visible=True,
        rangebreaks=[
            # NOTE: Below values are bound (not single values), ie. hide x to y
            dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]),  # hide weekends, eg. hide sat to before mon
            dict(bounds=[16, 9.5], pattern="hour"),  # hide hours outside of 9.30am-4pm
            # dict(values=["2019-12-25", "2020-12-24"])  # hide holidays (Christmas and New Year's, etc)
        ]
    )
    fig.update_layout(
        title='Stock Analysis',
        yaxis_title=f'{symbol} Stock'
    )

    fig.show()
```

here's [Plotly's doc](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#hiding-weekends-and-holidays).

Comment: I tried doing it here but it isn't working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71880639/react-js-plotly-remove-time-gaps-in-graph

Comment: Which points are not working? I have confirmed that it is continuous in my environment.

Answer (score 4):

You can set `rangebreaks` option:

1. you must find `missing` values(holiday,weekend,closed days etc.)
   You can use this two lines code
2. Place the `fig.update` before `fig.show()`.

   ```
   alldays =set(df.Datetime[0]+timedelta(x) for x in range((df.Datetime[len(df.Datetime)-1]- df.Datetime[0]).days))
   missing=sorted(set(alldays)-set(df.Datetime))

   fig.update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[dict(values=missing)])
   ```

Comment: Works perfrect to me! thanks

Answer (score 2):

TLDR:
I was stuck with same problem and couldn't found any solution from the plotly documentation. Only suggestion I found on plotly R community is to make the x axis as category instead of datetime. Still I couldn't make it work as the `fig.layout()` has no such property available.

For your code change the Datetime to string to force it to none datetime type axis

```
df["Datetime"] = df.index.dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
```

This should resolve issue the datetime gaps.

Comment: index doesn't need .dt if it's already in datetime format.

Answer (score 1):

We can set `rangebreaks` option:

1. fill `nan` where we have gaps (i.e. reindexing the dataframe);
2. create `datebreaks` for all `nan` values;
3. set rangebreak values on `xaxes` config

```
begin_date, end_date = [df.iloc[0].name, df.iloc[-1].name]
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(begin_date, end_date, freq='D'))
datebreaks = df['Close'][df_plot['Close'].isnull()].index
fig.update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[dict(values=datebreaks)])
```