# React Js Plotly Remove Time Gaps In Graph

Tags: reactjs, plotly, plotly.js

I am trying to plot stock data, but there are gaps in the graph where data for these time periods don't exist. How do I remove these gaps? I found that there is an update_xaxes function but I'm not sure how to apply it to my case.

[image: Stock data]

My code:

```
import React, { useState, Component, useEffect } from "react";
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';

export const Chart = () => {

    return (
        <div>
            <Plot
                data={[
                    {
                        x: data['dates'],
                        y: data['open_price'],
                        type: 'scatter'
                    }
                ]}
                layout={{
                    autosize: false,
                    width: 1500,
                    height: 800,
                 xaxis: {
                        color: 'red',
                        rangebreaks: {
                            bounds: ["sat", "mon"],
                            values: ["2015-12-25", "2016-01-01"],
                            bounds: [17, 9], pattern: "hour"
                        }
                    }
                }}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Is there any `rangebreaks` in javascript, and how to use them in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67296518/set-plotly-go-line-graph-rangebreaks-to-exclude-non-business-hours-and-weekends)? The official reference can be found [here](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-rangebreaks).

Comment: I am not sure how to use it in react plotly js

Comment: Then why not use time-series data as a string?

Comment: The dates plotly is using to graph my data is in string form

Comment: I followed the guide here: https://plotly.com/python/time-series/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xaxis: {
                        color: 'red',
                        rangebreaks: [
                            { bounds: ["sat", "mon"] },
                            {
                                values: ["2019-12-25"]
                            },
                            { bounds: [17, 9], pattern: "hour" }
                        ]
                    }
```

I fixed it by making rangebreaks an array.

Answer (score 0):

`react-ploty` allows configuring the underlying ploty configuration through props. The `data` props you're already using [accepts the same Traces Object than regular ploty](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/blob/master/README.md#basic-props). Therefore you can use [rangebreaks](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-rangebreaks) as suggested by @r-beginners to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: I am trying to use rangebreaks, see my code above. I am not sure why it isnt working.